# How to create two stage login page in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, authentication, jinja2

I have to create two login pages. One to return all the chocolates manufactured by company and other returns details of individual chocolates.

I have tried this but it not working.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST']) 
@app.route('/login2', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method =='POST':
        un = request.form['username']
        pw = request.form['password']
        #check if username and password is correct and store the result in check
        if check == "error":
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login2'))
    return render_template('login.html', error = error)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
def login2():
    error = None
    if request.method =='POST':
        un = request.form['username']
        pw = request.form['password']
        #check if username and password is correct and store the result in check
        if check=="error":
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login2.html', error=error)
```

But this gives an error which says can't build an url for login2. Did you mean login?
And i'm using standard templates for login html page

Comment: Your app route for login2 refers to login1 function instead of login2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route must be right above the function it calls, like this:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST']) 
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method =='POST':
        un = request.form['username']
        pw = request.form['password']
        #check if username and password is correct and store the result in check
        if check == "error":
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login2'))
    return render_template('login.html', error = error)


@app.route('/login2', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login2():
    error = None
    if request.method =='POST':
        un = request.form['username']
        pw = request.form['password']
        #check if username and password is correct and store the result in check
        if check=="error":
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login2.html', error=error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Maybe try to remove the number from your login2 function and use sg like def login_two instead?

Comment: Please use above code posted by Kata and post complete error trail here.